# Video doesn't upload to facebook wall android

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am uploading video using the following code

```
Request.Callback callback5 = new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {    
    // response will have an id if successful
    Log.e("HackBook", "Response = "+response);
    }
};
File tempFile;
try {
    tempFile = createTempFileFromAsset(getApplicationContext(), "video.mp4");
    Request request5 = Request.newUploadVideoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),
            tempFile, callback5);
    RequestAsyncTask task5 = new RequestAsyncTask(request5);
    task5.execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("HackBook", "failed to create temp file");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

public static File createTempFileFromAsset(Context context, String assetPath) 
        throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;

    try {
    AssetManager assets = context.getResources().getAssets();
    inputStream = assets.open(assetPath);

    File outputDir = context.getCacheDir(); // context being the
                        // Activity pointer
    File outputFile = File.createTempFile("prefix", assetPath,
        outputDir);
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    final int bufferSize = 1024 * 2;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int n = 0;
    while ((n = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }

    return outputFile;
    } finally {
    com.facebook.internal.Utility.closeQuietly(outStream);
    com.facebook.internal.Utility.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    }
}
```

it returns the following error message

```
 {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus:
 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An
 active access token must be used to query information about the
 current user.}, isFromCache:false}
```

Can you please guide me whats going wrong ?

Comment: any one have idea to post video into facebook wall?